# what is difference between success_url and get_success_url

Tags: django

```py
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'task/login.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tasks')
    # def get_success_url(self):
    #     return reverse_lazy('tasks')
```

In this case, I think success_url will work with no error, but there is error
It worked well using get_success_url method but i don't know what is difference between them.
Furthermore, I'd like to know how works method and attribute in Class.
Thanks

Comment: "but there is error" what error do you get? Both look valid (for at least recent versions of Django, since `get_success_url` can give an  error in some older Django versions if you use `reverse_lazy` instead of `reverse`)

Comment: if i use success_url atrribute, i get Page Not found at /accounts/profile Error. get_success_url method didn't give Error. it works successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code your view inherits from `LoginView`, which is why you seem to get the error. `LoginView` has a custom implementation of `get_success_url` which does not use `success_url`. This is because one can make links like `<login_url>?next=<some_other_url>` so that one can redirect a user to the page he was trying to access after he logs in.

If `next` is not provided as a GET or POST parameter or is an unsafe or invalid url `LoginView` uses the `next_page` attribute if it is set or uses `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. Hence for your case you can simply set `next_page` on your view:

```py
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'task/login.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    next_page = reverse_lazy('tasks')
```